# WCF basic deploymemt to iis7

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I am rather new to deployment and wcf and not sure why the following occurs

I have a VS2010 WCF project  which has  a single service.svc and associated contract with single lookup method GetStatus accepting and returning strings. As per recommendations I left the Web.config as generated and notice that it does not define end points.
Then it was deployed to local iis7 using publish with parameters
          ServiceURL: Localhost
          site/application : main/status

I then went to iis and observed that it is deployed under main/status folder structure

However when I try accessing using wcf test client by specifying

```
http://localhost/main/status/service.svc or
http://localhost/status/service.svc
```

I get the not found error.

```
Metadata from http://localhost/main/status/Status.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation
```

I get same error when tring to browse from iis.

Please see the config file (generated)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

any help would be great

Comment: Can you post on how your config looks like? Also a screenshot from IIS on where your .svc file is sitting would be easy to help

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the metadata enabled in your web.config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior>
    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values 
         below to false before deployment -->
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
  </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

If metadata is enabled then the service does not exist on that url. By default WCF will use basicHttpBinding and SOAP 1.1.

Comment: Hi This is already setup correctly                         <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>

Comment: @josephj1989 In that case your Url might be different. It's hard to say what is the correct path but if your svc file is named service.svc and you have not changed any settings then your url should be http://localhost:[port]/service.svc (Can you check your port in IIS settings (bindings)?) Also you can try to open your IIS, browse to the site in the left pane, right click, manage web site and browse, then append service.svc to the url. It will be hard to explain the complete procedure here so I'd suggest you look on-line for tutorials.